# BottomSheet not visible behind an imageView with onTouchListener once Screen is touched

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I have a imageview which  has a setOntouchlistener. when the image is touched  information is displayed about the touch area in the expanded bottom sheet.

When I run the app all is displayed as expected initially, I can see the peek of the bottomSheet at the bottom of the screen, which is displayed over the imageView.

However once I touch the screen the imageview is then displayed over the bottomsheet so I cannot see the bottomsheet.

when I comment out the setOnTouchListener for the imageview this is no longer a problem. I have also attempted using fragments for this leading to the exact same issue. Can Anyone suggest some solutions for this??

I have tried adding a touchlistener to the LinearLayout of the bottomSheet and the imageview in the bottomsheet. with return false but does not solve the issue.

Below are the extracts of the important pieces of code.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#fff"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="@dimen/activity_margin"

app:behavior_hideable="true"

app:behavior_peekHeight="50dp"
app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:weightSum="3">


</LinearLayout>


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/fragmentImageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="173dp"
    android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/locationInfoTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="173dp"
    android:text="Smellybottom" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

The setOntouchListener in my activity

```
  photoview2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            touchX = (int) event.getX();
            touchY = (int) event.getY();


            ///##frag//LocationInfoFragment fragobject2 = (LocationInfoFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.infoFragment) ;
            ///##frag//LinearLayout infoFragementLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.infoFragmentLayout);
            sheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
            ImageView fragmentImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fragmentImageView);
            TextView locationInfoTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.locationInfoTextView);
            ///##frag//infoFragementLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            for (InfoLocationInformation locationArrayVariable : mInfoLocationInformations) {
                if(touchX > locationArrayVariable.getXy().get(0) & touchX < locationArrayVariable.getXy().get(2) & touchY > locationArrayVariable.getXy().get(1) & touchY < locationArrayVariable.getXy().get(3)){
                    //Log.e(TAG, "Location information for " +  locationArrayVariable.getName()  );


                    if(locationArrayVariable.getType()<1 && infoButton.getBackgroundTintList().getDefaultColor()==-49023+100){

                        locationInfoTextView.setText(locationArrayVariable.getText());

                        sheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);




                    }else if(locationArrayVariable.getType()>0 && locationArrayVariable.getType()<3 && (barButton.getBackgroundTintList().getDefaultColor()==-524991+100 || restaurentButton.getBackgroundTintList().getDefaultColor()==-10879633+100)){


                        locationInfoTextView.setText(locationArrayVariable.getText());

                        sheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);




                    }else if(locationArrayVariable.getType()>2 && locationArrayVariable.getType()<5 && (cafeButton.getBackgroundTintList().getDefaultColor()==-31949+100 || restaurentButton.getBackgroundTintList().getDefaultColor()==-10879633+100)){
                        //fragmentImageView.setImageBitmap();
                        locationInfoTextView.setText(locationArrayVariable.getText());

                        sheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);




                    }else if(locationArrayVariable.getType()>4 && cafeButton.getBackgroundTintList().getDefaultColor()==-31949+100){

                        locationInfoTextView.setText(locationArrayVariable.getText());
                        sheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);




                    }


                }
            }
            Log.e(TAG, "touch coordinates X" + touchX +" Y "+ touchY  );
            ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
            view.bringToFront();
            viewTransformation(view, event);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

the .xml for the activity.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:design="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">



<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/limerickMapImageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:src="@drawable/limerickmap" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/centreButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/centre"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/linkBlue" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/restaurentButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="270dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="570dp"
    android:src="@drawable/restaurent"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/green1" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/barButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="340dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="570dp"
    android:src="@drawable/bar"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/blue3" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/infoButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="138dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="570dp"
    android:src="@drawable/info" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/cafeButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="205dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="570dp"
    android:src="@drawable/cafe"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/orange1" />



<include
    layout="@layout/bottom_sheet"
     />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution I removed
      view.bringToFront();